# Sending a model through remote functions? ROBLOX

Tags: server, client, remote-server, roblox

well hello there,

So I'll get right to the point..

Everyone knows that in Roblox you have a ReplicatedStorage (for Client and Server) and a ServerStorage (only for Server).

So I want to store all my assets in ServerStorage .. you know, since exploiters/hackers can't see the ServerStorage if they tried.

However my game has virtual worlds..meaning that the client sees different objects than the other clients at any given time, so I can't just load an object from a server scripts because then everyone will see it.

Heres the question: Can I perhaps set up a remote function that lets the Client invoke the Server, and then the Server returns a model object or its location or something like that? And can I then use the Client to load the model into the player's workspace?

^That way I can securely store my important game assets in the serverstorage

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "**Yes, you can!**"

First off, you're going to want to create a RemoteFunction in the ReplicatedStorage. Call this RemoteFunction, 'GetModel'

Now, we're going to set up a local script inside of the StarterPack. This local script should have the following code:

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RF = RS:WaitForChild("GetModel")

local model = RF:InvokeServer("ModelName") -- This code can go anywhere you'd like it to go. 'ModelName' is the name of the model you want to get.

print(model.Name) -- This will print the model's name.
```

Alright, so we've setup our code to invoke the remotefunction. Now, let's make that RemoteFunction do something. We'll create a server script inside of ServerScriptService. Here's the code:

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RF = RS:WaitForChild("GetModel")
RF.OnServerInvoke = function(player, modelName)
    local model = game.ServerStorage:FindFirstChild(modelName)
    if model == nil then
        return nil
    else
        return model
    end

end
```

Most of this is basic code, and from what you said in the question it seems you understand lua fine. Hope I helped you! :)

Comment: i tried it, but it doesnt work. The model is a nil value because the client can't access server storage and doesn't know where the model is

Comment: Yes, but the server can access server storage. It's impossible to have the client access the server storage although you could setup events to have the server access the server storage. Sorry if I misinterpreted your question.